# xslt playing an mp3 via xml

Tags: xml, xslt, mp3

I have an xml feed and I need to play an mp3 from the feed.  I have set up the player

```
<div class="musicplayer">
  <div id="musicplayercontainer060251712481gbakw0201569t"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var flashvars = {file:"music/betty.mp3",as:"0"};
       var params = {wmode: "transparent"};
       var attributes = {};
       swfobject.embedSWF("images/player.swf",  
       "musicplayercontainer060251712481gbakw0201569t", "23", "23", 
       "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
</div>
```

and it works fine if I pass the mp3 directly, but I have to pass it from the xml so I replaced the betty.mp3 with `<xsl:value-of select="clipUrl"/>` but it won't play.

It is just when I replace betty.mp3 like

```
<div class="musicplayer">
  <div id="musicplayercontainer060251712481gbakw0201569t"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var flashvars = {file:"<xsl:value-of select="clipUrl"/>",as:"0"};
       var params = {wmode: "transparent"};
       var attributes = {};
       swfobject.embedSWF("images/player.swf",
       "musicplayercontainer060251712481gbakw0201569t", "23", "23",
       "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
</div>
```

Is there a syntax I need to use?
e.g.

```
var flashvars = {file:"<xsl:value-of select="clipUrl"/>",as:"0"};
```

Comment: It might be better if you show us the code that __doesn't__ work rather than the code that does.

Answer (score 0):

Personally if you don't have any XHTML based expando hangups you could do this instead:-

```
<div class="musicplayer">
  <div id="musicplayercontainer060251712481gbakw0201569t"
      audioSrc="{clipUrl}"
  ></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var elem = document.getElementById("musicplayercontainer060251712481gbakw0201569t");
    var flashvars = {file:elem.getAttribute("audioSrc"), as:"0"};
    var params = {wmode: "transparent"};
    var attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF("images/player.swf", "musicplayercontainer060251712481gbakw0201569t", "23", "23", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
  </script>
</div>
```

This way you don't embedded xsl instructions in your script code where output encoding may be messing things up.